# Render to a texture2d XNA

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, texture2d

I need to render a sprite in a texture2d so that this texture can later be render on the screen, but at the same time I need to access the pixels of this modified texture so, if I add let's say a sprite in the texture and I call a get pixel function in a coordinate where the sprite was then it should give me the new pixel values that correspond to the sprite (that has been blended with the texture2d).

I am using xna 4.0 not 3.5 or less.

thanks.

the equivalent of Graphics.FromImage(img).DrawImage(... in GDI

I tried this and failed

```
public static Texture2D DrawSomething(Texture2D old, int X, int Y, int radius) {
var pp = Res.game.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters;
var r = new RenderTarget2D(Res.game.GraphicsDevice, old.Width, old.Height, false, pp.BackBufferFormat, pp.DepthStencilFormat,
pp.MultiSampleCount, RenderTargetUsage.DiscardContents);
Res.game.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(r);
var s = new SpriteBatch(r.GraphicsDevice);
s.Begin();
s.Draw(old, new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);
s.Draw(Res.picture, new Rectangle(X - radius / 2, Y - radius / 2, radius, radius), Color.White);
s.End();
Res.game.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
return r;
}
```

Res.game is basically a pointer to the main game form and Res.picture is a random texture2d

Answer (score 0):

Use a `RenderTarget2D`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.rendertarget2d.aspx

Comment: ya sorry i was pasting it. check again

Comment: if you create a new `RenderTarget2D` every update, call `RenderTarget2D.Dispose()` after you set the render target to null or put it in a using statement

Comment: ok i did, but then when I access its pixels later, it says it throws an error 'Cannot access a disposed object.'

Comment: If you need to change it later, store it as an instance variable instead of creating one every time.

Comment: what do u mean? it is stored as a variable after that. can u give me a simple method example of how to do this please

Comment: You'll have to slightly change your design, or you can try to dispose of the variable you assign the result of this method to, after you use it

Answer (score 0):

If possible, avoid creating a new render target every time. Create it outside of the method and reuse it for best performance.

Here some pseudo-code:

```
public Texture2D DrawOnTop(RenderTarget2D target, Texture2D oldTexture, Texture2D picture)
{
    SetRenderTarget(target);

    Draw(oldTexture);
    Draw(picture);

    SetRenderTarget(null);

    return target;
}
```

If the size changes frequently and you cannot reuse the target, at least dispose the previous one, like [annonymously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9544691/925580) suggested in the comments. Each new target will consume memory, unless you release the resource in time. But dispose it **after** you used it in a shader or did whatever you wanted to do with it. Once disposed it is gone.